# Two linearLayout inside relative layout in order to show each content in new line

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i'm trying to show each content ( imageview and text view ) in new line but i coudn't succeed.
i'm doing that programmatically , here is my code.

```
RelativeLayout grp=new RelativeLayout(this);
            grp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            grp.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

            TextView test=new TextView(this);
            test.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            test.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>text here</p>"));
            LinearLayout ln=new LinearLayout(this);
            ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageA);
            img.setFadingEdgeLength(10);
            ln.addView(img);

            ln.addView(test);
            ln.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            LinearLayout ln0=new LinearLayout(this);
            grp.addView(ln);



            TextView test1=new TextView(this);
            test1.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            test1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>text here</p>"));
            LinearLayout ln1=new LinearLayout(this);
            ImageView img1=new ImageView(this);
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageB);
            img1.setFadingEdgeLength(10);
            ln1.addView(img1);
            //ln1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            ln1.addView(test1);
            ln1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            grp.addView(ln1);

            setContentView(grp);
```

what sould i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and set the linearlayout's orientation to vertical with setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

Comment: ... and do it with a layout!

Comment: Many thanks Alex , just an other question my app is dynamic thats why i'm building it  only programmatically is it good this way ?

Comment: Thanks Blake for your reply.

Comment: @user1228988 It depends, maybe you can create some xml layout and inflate it when you want to use it.My personal opinion writing code for layout is much slower then creating the corresponding xml file, also it will be a pain to keep your code clean and readable.